# Is there a Simple OSLC Metamodel Showing Entities and Relationships?

Tags: metamodel, oslc

There seems to be any amount of RDF-format for the OSLC but what I'm looking for is a simple E-R-like view of the OSLC metamodel which shows the concepts and relationships which can be used to understand the organisation and possible queries.

Is there a (graphic) representation of the OSLC metamodel anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are after a simple graphical diagram, you can find UML models under this [Lyo-Docs 
 repo](https://github.com/eclipse/lyo.docs/tree/master/uml-model). you can find the source .emx files, as well as .png snapshots under the folder "OSLC-V2/images/".

I you are developing OSLC applications, you might want to consider the modelling tool [Lyo Designer](https://oslc.github.io/developing-oslc-applications/eclipse_lyo/lyo-designer).
There, you can find a graphical model of the OSLC Core and Domain concepts. The models are based on a OSLC-specific modelling language. Lyo Designer allows you define/extend your own models, from which you can generate an OSLC application, based on the [Eclipse Lyo SDK](https://www.eclipse.org/lyo/).

I here assume you are aware of the java class implementations of [the OSLC Core concepts in Eclipse Lyo](https://github.com/eclipse/lyo.core/tree/master/oslc4j-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/lyo/oslc4j/core/model). There is also an implementation of [the domain specifications](https://github.com/eclipse/lyo.client/tree/master/oslc4j-client/src/main/java/org/eclipse/lyo/oslc4j/client/resources).

Comment: Also see https://oslc-op.github.io/oslc-specs/specs/core/discovery.html#discoveryApproaches

Comment: Thanks. Why diagrams don't form part of the OSLC spec is baffling.

Comment: I can agree. I will forward your comment to the committee. http://docs.oasis-open.org/oslc-core/oslc-core/v3.0/oslc-core-v3.0-part1-overview.html

Comment: It would help if the OSLC provided a ticket system so that comments / requests / bugs can be raised against any or the products to improve its quality.

Comment: @wikitect! OSLC is a specification, so depending on the product you have in mind, there are different reporting systems. What did you have in mind?

Comment: @jad I reaise that the OSLC is a spec. Ticketing systems can be used with documents - see the TRAK Metamodel spec on Sourceforge  at https://sourceforge.net/p/trakmetamodel/bugs-metamodel/